# How do I traverse relationships when populating models from queries?

Tags: plugin-development, relations, elementcriteriamodel, elementtype

I have three models / records - Journals, Issues, and Articles. Articles each BELONG_TO an Issue. Issues each BELONG_TO a journal. Issues have a date on which they've been published, and I am trying to find the most recent issue (by cover date) for a given journal.

I have the following code in a method in the IssueService:

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria('Articles_Issue');
$criteria->journalId = $journal->id;
$criteria->limit = 1;

$query = craft()->elements->buildElementsQuery($criteria);
$query->order('issues.coverDate desc');

$issue = Articles_IssueModel::populateModel($query->queryRow());
```

This all works well and good and I am returned the appropriate Article_IssueModel. However, when trying to access $issue->articles, I get zero back. Normally when I load the issue through `craft()->elements->findByElementId($issue->id);`, the articles in the relationship are available.

Editing the code I pasted above to include the following (after populating issue model):

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria('Articles_Article');
$criteria->issueId = $issue->id;
$art = $criteria->findAll();
print_r(count($issue->articles));
print_r(count($art));
```

prints 0, followed by 2.

So it seems to me that calling BaseModel::populateModel is not enough to load the model's relationships. I recognize that I am (possibly?) skipping a step in not instantiating any Records, but if I change the issue loading code to the following:

```
$issueRecord = Articles_IssueRecord::model();
$issueRecord->populateRecord($query->queryRow());
$issue = Articles_IssueModel::populateModel($issueRecord);
```

I still get zero articles when accessed via `$issue->articles`. Is there a way to get the issue to load its related articles without manually loading them via `ElementsService`?

Please note, I am building many other service calls and views using this plugin, and I have double checked that foreign keys are being populated and the relationships defined on the records are working properly. Also, I can post additional code if I've missed something.

Comment: Have you tried using `$criteria->relatedTo`